# How can I demux avi?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, avi

I want to demux the audio from avi files, so that the files are lossless. I tried both Yamb and Ffmpeg. Both produce files less than 1 MB (for a video of 80 MB), which are unplayable through VLC. I tried avidemux, and it says it can't export in copy mode.

Comment: Paste the console output of the ffmpeg command you ran.

Comment: Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/n0E2e07P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your audio is PCM, but you're trying to streamcopy to AAC, which won't work.

To extract the audio to WAV, use

```
ffmpeg -i DSCN5008.AVI -acodec copy -y a.wav
```

To **transcode** the audio to AAC, use

```
ffmpeg -i DSCN5008.AVI -acodec aac -y a.aac
```

Note that AAC isn't lossless. But FLAC is a lossless and compressed codec.

```
ffmpeg -i DSCN5008.AVI -acodec flac -y a.flac
```